# How to disply images in grails which is stored out-side of the grails project

Tags: grails

i'm using grails file uploader plugin to upload image file to specific location in my local machine, and also i'm able to download it from the same location,
but my problem is, i'm not able to display tht image in my gsp file.
i'e in img tag if i give the src of tht image file which is outside the grails project.
it displays only the images which is inside the project. is it possible to display images in that way ( without the help of domain class )

Answer (score 0):

Build a controller that has a single action, say 'image', that takes the path as the parameter (or id is better) and then just output that file from disk and set-header content-type correctly and you can just use:

`<img src='${linkTo(controller: "image", action: "image", id: myId")}' alt="My pic" />`